# How to generate SQL with specific table columns using BQL

Tags: acumatica

When I join two DAC in BQL syntax its generates SQL which selects all the columns from both tables. What if I want to select one table's columns in order to reach good execution plan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to look into `PXProjection` where the Columns are defined as the fields within the projection class. `PXProjection` is like a SQL view as a DAC in Acumatica. Just search the Acumatica source for `PXProjection` and you should find many examples. Note that within the class you need to set `BqlField` for each "column" so the process knows which table.field your projection field maps to.

Quick join PXProjection below. In this example there will be only 1 column in the DAC and it maps to `APRegister.docType`

```
[PXProjection(typeof(Select2<APRegister, 
        InnerJoin<APInvoice, On<APInvoice.docType, Equal<APRegister.docType>, 
            And<APInvoice.refNbr, Equal<APRegister.refNbr>>>, 
        InnerJoin<APPayment, On<APPayment.docType, Equal<APRegister.docType>, 
            And<APPayment.refNbr, Equal<APRegister.refNbr>>>>>, 
        Where<APRegister.docType, Equal<APDocType.quickCheck>, 
            Or<APRegister.docType, Equal<APDocType.voidQuickCheck>>>>), Persistent = true)]
[Serializable]
public partial class APQuickCheck : APRegister
{
    #region DocType
    public new abstract class docType : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    [PXDBString(3, IsKey = true, IsFixed = true, BqlField = typeof(APRegister.docType))]
    [PXDefault(APDocType.QuickCheck)]
    [APQuickCheckType.List()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Type", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible, Enabled = false)]
    [PXFieldDescription]
    public override String DocType
    {
        get
        {
            return this._DocType;
        }
        set
        {
            this._DocType = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```